# New Customer measure

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

Good day!

I have this measure which used to identify which clients are new based on the parameter (6 month) and also month & year of their ETD.

```
New Customers = //Cus
VAR CustomerTM = VALUES(Customer[Client])
VAR PriorCustomer = CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(Customer[Client]),
FILTER(ALL('Customer'),
'Customer'[ETD] > Min('Customer'[ETD] ) - Parameter[Parameter Value] && 'Customer'[ETD] < MIN('Customer'[ETD])))
return
COUNTROWS(
EXCEPT(CustomerTM,PriorCustomer))
```

My raw data:

[image: Raw Data]

There are no problems with the coding until the 'branch' slicer is added.

***Based on my raw data, Nike should consider new customers for SIN branch in January, but for TYO branch in February.***

But this code as a result, NIKE only had new customers on January, is there any part that I was missed?

[image: Slicer 'Jan' and Branch 'SIN']

[image: Slicer 'Feb' and Branch 'TYO']

Attached with pbix: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mvW9opym6Ot2AlyZy0m0kl2rDeB4P2Wv/view?usp=sharing

Greatly appreciated any helps provided! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try ALLEXCEPT() instesd of ALL in your FILTER. All() removes all filters and slicers from you data. Only Parameter[Parameter Value] infuences your FILTER. So if you do not change it in all other cases you have the same result.

```
   FILTER(
         ALLEXCEPT('Customer',Customer[Branch])
         ,AND(
             'Customer'[ETD] > Min('Customer'[ETD] ) - Parameter[Parameter Value]
             ,'Customer'[ETD] < MIN('Customer'[ETD])
         )
   )
```